# How Do I build an IBM WebService Thin Client app that uses SSL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, websphere

I have been provided with some code that is said to demonstrate calling a SOAP web Service using the IBM webservices-thinclient jar file

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work for SSL and the web service I am trying to hit only provides an HTTPS endpoint.

So, I need to configure the app to use SSL but it is proving to be stupefyingly difficult.

Much of the documentation that I can find is confusing, but it seems to suggest that I need to configure a file called ssl.client.props. I did this ...

It also suggests that I need to set the normal javax.net.ssl properties for truststore and keystore. I did that too ...

It also suggests that I need to change the Security provider for my JDK. I did that too .... ( but I was beginning to lose faith by this point )

NOTHING WORKS - all I ever get is `WSWS3740E: Error: No SSL configuration is available for endpoint - https://whatever`.

Has anyone ever done this? I'm using the Oracle JDK ( Java 8 ) and version 7.0 of the webservices-thinclient.jar

***EDIT***

The main part of my code looks like this ...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, ServiceException, JAXBException {

        System.setProperty("com.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL", "file:C:\\logs\\ssl.client.props");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "file:C:\\environment-specific\\dev\\truststore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "trustpassword");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "file:C:\\environment-specific\\dev\\keystore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "keypassword");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","jks");
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.ibm.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringBeans.xml");
        AuthenticationService_PortType service = (AuthenticationService_PortType) context.getBean("authenticationServiceWebServiceImpl");
        AuthenticationVerifyRequest authRequest = createRequest();
        AuthenticationVerifyResponse authenticationVerifyResponse = service.authenticationVerify(authRequest);

        System.out.println(authenticationVerifyResponse.toString());
}
```

My `ssl.client.props` file looks like this

```
com.ibm.ssl.protocol=SSL
com.ibm.ssl.trustManager=SunX509
com.ibm.ssl.keyManager=SunX509
com.ibm.ssl.contextProvider=SunJSSE

# keystore information
com.ibm.ssl.keystoreName=ClientDefaultKeyStore
com.ibm.ssl.keyStore=C:\\environment-specific\\dev\\keystore.jks
com.ibm.ssl.keyStorePassword=keypassword
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreProvider=SUN
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreFileBased=true

# truststore information
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreName=ClientDefaultTrustStore
com.ibm.ssl.trustStore=C:\\environment-specific\\dev\\truststore.jks
com.ibm.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustpassword
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreFileBased=true
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreReadOnly=false
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreProvider=SUN
```

Any conbinations of `com.ibm.ssl.*` and `javax.net.ssl.*` in the system properties and the config file always lead to the same result.

Comment: Did you try to run it with explicitly providing ssl config like this `java -Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:///C:\\logs\\ssl.client.props`?

Comment: @Gas - Just tried it - same result. Could it have anything to do with the Spring config do you think?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please share a part of your code where you configure and initialize SSL requset.
2. Each ssl connector might need configuration either by setting properties in code or by loading config. See this http://garywaddell.com/2011/10/07/wsws3740e-error-no-ssl-configuration-is-available-for-endpoint/
3. For config a ssl connector needs SSL ciphers  and keystores (private and truststore). Depending if you use javax or IBM library keystore format will be different

IBM SSL implementation likes kdb format (GSkit, gsk8apicmd)
Java implementation uses jks (keytool)

See this https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013926228

4. Endpoints certs you are connecting to must be trusted (cert chain in truststore) or certs verification disabled in your connector (don't do this on prod )

Comment: I've added my code to the original question. I think I've followed all the steps in the articles you posted.

Comment: @DaveH ,  Try enabling debug ` -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` , example here [debug ssl](http://www.hansvandeweghe.com/2016/10/07/debugging-isam-java-runtime-ssl-handhake-issues-in-websphere/)